# How do I create shortcut commands in the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

For example, instead of typing all 5 commands in my terminal:

```
command 1
command 2
command 3
command 4
command 5
```

I just want to enter one command that runs all 5 commands above:

```
command everything
```

Is that possible? What would I need to edit in Ubuntu to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're running a bash shell, you can type

`alias commandall='command1 ; command2 ; command3 ; command4; command5'`

Then `commandall` will run these commands

You can put the alias in your `~/.bashrc` file and it will be there whenever you log in.

Answer (score 4):

create a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
command3
```

then set its mode to executable

```
chmod a+x commandall
```

then you can call it from the command line

```
./commandall
```

if you put it in a directory in your PATH, you can call it like any other command.

```
~/bin
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, though the question seems like it belongs on serverfault rather than SO.

Comment: 1 Shebang is wrong. 2 Needs to be superuser to do chmod. 3 Hasn't explained what commandall is.

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script, mark it executable, put in in your path and then run it?

Alternatively you might write a shell function, put it in your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: This answer is understandable only to people who already know how to do it.

Comment: But "how to write a shell script" or "how to write a shell function" would work better as a search term than "how do i create shortcut commands in the ubuntu terminal".

Comment: You intended your answer to provide better search keys rather than being an answer itself?

Comment: Well it *is* an answer. It's not a *complete*, step-by-step illustrated answer, luckily better people e.g. simon, Dennis Sheil, Jason have come up with better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for bash aliases -- try starting [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) :)

Comment: I think an alias would be a good choice if it was one command for another. or an addition of paramaters for default command.... but not one command for multiple commands. In that case I would say a script is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks guys! Such quick responses. Bash aliases solved the issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: @jason -- in this case, I disagree...  Dennis has spelled it out explicitly above.

Comment: you are right. After seeing his usage of the alias. I can see the ease and functionality. (I stand corrected)

Answer (score 1):

If you want every command be executed in the order, `command1 && command2 && command3 && command4 && command5` should do.  You could save it in a shell script and call the script when you need.

If the order of execution is not so important,

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
command4 &
command5 &
```

should do.

You could as well mix and match if you need some other order of execution.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/29428-help-execute-programs-sequence-through-batch.html):

```
$ (stsrun -v devel area1.exp; stsrun -v devel prime1.exp; stsrun -v devel treat.exp) &
```